# LI does not abide by ancestor's padding

Tags: html, css, html-lists

My LI does not abide by an ancestor's padding setting:

[image]

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="expUnit">
    <h4>Company</h4>
    <p>Lorem ipsum.</p>
    <ul class="project-list">
        <li>Line 1</li>
        <li>Line 2</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.expUnit 
{
    line-height:17px;
    color: #444;
    border-left:1px solid #fadc66;
    padding-left:15px;
}

.expUnit .project-list li
{
    list-style-type: circle;
}
```

However in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ux2hm/9/), it does indent it.  What could be the reason I don't get and alignment of bullets with 'Lorem ipsum'?

Comment: There must be some CSS reset that's causing this. Do update your jsFiddle with the entire CSS that you have.

Comment: Hmm .. no CSS reset there. Does your page loads a few other CSS files? Do provide the codes you wrote inside `<head>` tag in your HTML page.

Comment: I do have `reset.css` in the links

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're applying the padding to your parent container, and not your `project-list`.

Also, since you're using `reset.css`, you'll need to override the `ul{padding:0}` with a more specific declaration.

Try:

```
.expUnit ul
  {
    padding-left:15px;
    list-style-type: circle;
  }
```

Also, double check that your CSS file is being called after `reset.css`